# Removing a Lock From a Field in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, lock

I'm trying to remove the lock on a map layer in ArcGIS Online that belongs to a map being used in field collection. It's missing some data. I've tried un-indexing it and that did nothing.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Picture below added for clarification.

[image]

I've tried configuring popup in map viewer to allow for the field to be edited, but it's grayed out and I'm unable to do so.

[image]

Comment: long winded way https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000018451 (but unlock, not lock attributes)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I'm afraid that's not working either. The "edit" option in the configure popup section is grayed out, so I can't check it.